# How do I fix indirect leaks (complained about by GCC ASAN) not allocated using new or malloc?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, address-sanitizer

I'm running a piece of code which allocates memory using `std::shared_ptr<>`. However, on shutting down the process, GCC ASAN complaints of things like `Indirect leak of 91723904 byte(s) in 383 object(s)` and there are no direct leaks.

Error -

```
Indirect leak of 91723904 byte(s) in 383 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f93658497c0 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xef7c0)
    #1 0xc0275b in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:111
    #2 0xc01eaf in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:436
    #3 0xc01087 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/allocated_ptr.h:97
    #4 0xc000d3 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short, unsigned short, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, Horizon::Zone::Game::Map*, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map> const&, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, unsigned short&&, unsigned short&&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:660
    #5 0xbfeda1 in std::__shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short, unsigned short, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map> const&, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, unsigned short&&, unsigned short&&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1328
    #6 0xbfd2be in std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short, unsigned short, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map> const&, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, unsigned short&&, unsigned short&&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&) (/home/travis/build/horizonxyz/horizon/build/bin/Debug/zone+0xbfd2be)
    #7 0xbfb57b in std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map> std::allocate_shared<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map>, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short, unsigned short, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&>(std::allocator<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map> const&, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, unsigned short&&, unsigned short&&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&) (/home/travis/build/horizonxyz/horizon/build/bin/Debug/zone+0xbfb57b)
    #8 0xbfa076 in std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map> std::make_shared<Horizon::Zone::Game::Map, std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short, unsigned short, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&>(std::shared_ptr<Horizon::Zone::Game::MapThreadContainer>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, unsigned short&&, unsigned short&&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr.h:723
    #9 0xbf4371 in Horizon::Zone::Game::MapManager::LoadMapCache() /home/travis/build/horizonxyz/horizon/src/Server/Zone/Game/Map/MapManager.cpp:107
    #10 0xbf06f6 in Horizon::Zone::Game::MapManager::initialize() /home/travis/build/horizonxyz/horizon/src/Server/Zone/Game/Map/MapManager.cpp:49
    #11 0x42e82b in Horizon::Zone::ZoneMain::initialize_core() /home/travis/build/horizonxyz/horizon/src/Server/Zone/Zone.cpp:145
    #12 0x42f656 in main /home/travis/build/horizonxyz/horizon/src/Server/Zone/Zone.cpp:223
    #13 0x7f936372982f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
```

As seen above this is allocated using shared_ptr which doesn't require objects to be explicitly freed. But then again, there would need to be an internal call from the STL to delete the object which I think isn't happening as the process ends? Or that GCC isn't able to capture it.

Comment: If you have a circular data structure built with shared_ptrs, there will be a leak.

Comment: @n.m. I've also tested this with clang's ASAN, shouldn't it complaint about it as well? AFAIK there isn't a circular ownership of shared ptrs.

Comment: If one complains and the other doesn't, there's probably a problem with one of them :) Maybe also try valgrind.